# Multiple scenes with the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

I've been experimenting with multiple scenes in Blender. I put together 3 separate scenes. All the scenes use text and the orthographic camera. What I am attempting to do is create a simple text pre-roll for videos.

Anyway each scene is a copy of the previous scene with different text. Each scene had 60 frames. So when I put all this together I went into the sequence video editor and simply added the different scenes. I selected all the scenes and tried rendering the entire animation.

I had all the scenes selected and staggered out so they weren't on top of each other in the sequence. When I set my animation to 180 frames and tried to render it all out as a single H264 it didn't work. Then I placed all the strips from front to back and made a mega-strip and tried again. This didn't work either. It looks like my only option is to render each scene individually and then put them together as movies in the video editor.

Does anyone know if this can be done just using the scenes in the video editor?

Answer (score 2):

It looks good to me. It may due to the render settings among the scenes, especially the one where your VSE sequence locates, since separate scenes have separate settings.

Here is **[demo file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26612)**. FYI, hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I wound up answering my own question. I did have render the scenes separately and then combine them in a new blender file as a single movie.

Comment: Nice. but as I demostrated, you can actually do it within a single .blend file. :)

Comment: :(  the link above is broken

Comment: @SHC Hi, sorry for that. I posted this answer nearly three years ago. I cannot find it either. But I think I've clearly made the point literally.  :)